# Print to EMF file on Windows

Tags: windows, printing

I have a vector image that I need to convert to EMF in order to insert it into a Microsoft Office document. I do not have Visio installed, and Cairo will not convert the image cleanly, therefore I started looking for alternatives.

Since the Windows print stack internally uses EMF (which is the internal format used by the GDI) and then converts from EMF to the printer’s respective format, I wonder if there is a way to bypass the final conversion step and print directly to an EMF file (or siphon off the EMF file from the spooler somehow). Does anybody know of a way to do this?